# Resizing a video container

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I'm trying to get this video to be half 75% or 50% smaller (but back to 100% on mobile view). I'm not sure why but adding a width of 75% to .video-container makes it smaller but adding a height of 75% does nothing. Presumably editing the child element is not right as this just needs to be 100% the size of the parent absolutely.

Why is this not resizing properly?

```css
.video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.video-container iframe, .video-container object, .video-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/* OTHER IRRELEVANT STUFF BELOW */
#first-sec {
    background: lightblue;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 150px 10% 100px 10%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 62px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
}
p {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
a.cta-button {
 border: none;
 border-radius: 6px;
 padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: orange;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section id="first-sec">
  <h1>header 1 here</h1>
    <p>paragraph 1 here.</p>
    <article class="video-container">
        <iframe width="100%" height="auto" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-YXf0-_WMTU?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen class="video"></iframe>
    </article>
    <p>paragraph 2 here:</p>
    <a class="cta-button" href="#">button</a>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure why but adding a width of 75% to .video-container makes it smaller but adding a height of 75% does nothing.

Because the trick behind this method is that there is no height in play at all, and the element is spanned up by the padding instead - this is what makes “respecting the aspect ratio” work here in the first place, using width & height only you could not achieve that.

If you change the width for `.video-container`, it won’t work, because padding in percent is based on the *containing block’s* width - meaning, you will need to insert an additional container element:

```css
.video-container {
  width: 50%;
}
.video-container-inner {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.video-container iframe, .video-container object, .video-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/* OTHER IRRELEVANT STUFF BELOW */
#first-sec {
    background: lightblue;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 150px 10% 100px 10%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 62px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
}
p {
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 300;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
a.cta-button {
 border: none;
 border-radius: 6px;
 padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: orange;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section id="first-sec">
  <h1>header 1 here</h1>
    <p>paragraph 1 here.</p>
    <article class="video-container">
      <div class="video-container-inner">
        <iframe width="100%" height="auto" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/-YXf0-_WMTU?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen class="video"></iframe>
      </div>
    </article>
    <p>paragraph 2 here:</p>
    <a class="cta-button" href="#">button</a>
    </section>
```